# How can I create a function that when passed a type of Enum, checks the value of a variable is within that Enums bounds?

Tags: c#

I am using this code to check the value of a row in the database is within bounds:

```
public int GetIntSetting(SET setting, int nullState)
{
    var val = int.TryParse(GetStringSetting(setting, nullState.ToString()), out int parsed) ? parsed : nullState;
    if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TH), val))
        return val;
    else
        return nullState;
}
```

It works but I would like to extend this such as the type of Enum is passed into the function.  Something like this:

```
public int GetIntSetting(SET setting, int nullState, Enum enumType)
{
    var val = int.TryParse(GetStringSetting(setting, nullState.ToString()), out int parsed) ? parsed : nullState;
    // I need the following line to be able to use enumType instead of TH
    if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TH), val))
        return val;
    else
        return nullState;
}
```

which would be called like these example calls:

```
Settings.th = (TH)App.DB.GetIntSetting(SET.Th, 0, TH);
Settings.cfs = (LANG)App.DB.GetIntSetting(SET.Cfs, 0, LANG);
```

How can I pass the parameter TH into the function and have the function check that the value?

Comment: You don't need to do it yourself, it already exists: `System.Enum.IsDefined( ... )`.

Comment: Hello Dai, can you give an example using my code.  I'm not really clear on how I could implement that in the function.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter should be of type "Type", and it should work (you could also provide this method with a generics declaration if you wish):

```
    public int GetIntSetting(SET setting, int nullState, Type enumType)
{
    var val = int.TryParse(GetStringSetting(setting, nullState.ToString()), out int parsed) ? parsed : nullState;
    if (Enum.IsDefined(enumType, val))
        return val;
    else
        return nullState;
}
```

And the usage would be:

```
    Settings.th = (TH)App.DB.GetIntSetting(SET.Th, 0, typeof(TH));
    Settings.cfs = (LANG)App.DB.GetIntSetting(SET.Cfs, 0, typeof(LANG));
```

Comment: Thanks, trying this now

Comment: Since it is a public function so it makes sense to check for enumType.IsEnum

Answer (score 3):

I would do it with generics instead:

```
public T GetIntSetting<T>(string setting, int nullState) where T : System.Enum
{
    var val = int.TryParse(GetStringSetting(setting, nullState.ToString()), out int parsed) ? parsed : nullState;
    if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), val))
        return (T)val;
    else
        return (T)nullState;
}
```

Than you dont need to cast the result when you use the function. And since there is a generic enum constraint there is no risk of sending in a type that is not an enum

```
Settings.th = App.DB.GetIntSetting<TH>(SET.Th, 0);
Settings.cfs = App.DB.GetIntSetting<LANG>(SET.Cfs, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in this example I created a generic function which can take any enum type and return a Boolean if the value is present or not.

```
public enum enumA : int
{
    item1 = 0,
    item2 = 1,
    item3 = 2
}

public enum Day
   { Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat };

public class PassACustomDataTypeFController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        bool b1 = CheckIfPresent<enumA>(5);
        bool b2 = CheckIfPresent<Day>(5);
        return View();
    }

    private bool CheckIfPresent<T>(object val) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Wrong argument");
        }
        var expr = Expression.Call(typeof(Enum).GetMethod("IsDefined", new Type[] { typeof(Type), typeof(object) }), 
                                   Expression.Constant(typeof(T)),
                                   Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(val),
                                                      typeof(object)
                                                      )
                                   );
        var retVal = Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(expr).Compile()();
        return retVal;
    }

}
```